# getting errors when scrapping data with kimurai ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, kimurai

FATAL -- web_scrapper_spider: Spider: stopped: {:spider_name=>"web_scrapper_spider", :status=>:failed, :error=>"#<NameError: uninitialized constant URI::HTTP\n\n      raise InvalidUrlError, "Requested url is invalid: #{url}" unless URI.parse(url).kind_of?(URI::HTTP)\n                                                                                                 >", :environment=>"development", :start_time=>2022-11-17 19:03:32.418101772 +0530, :stop_time=>2022-11-17 19:03:32.420534612 +0530, :running_time=>"0s", :visits=>{:requests=>0, :responses=>0}, :items=>{:sent=>0, :processed=>0}, :events=>{:requests_errors=>{}, :drop_items_errors=>{}, :custom=>{}}}

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/kimurai-1.4.0/lib/kimurai/base.rb:194:in `request_to': uninitialized constant URI::HTTP (NameError)

```
  raise InvalidUrlError, "Requested url is invalid: #{url}" unless URI.parse(url).kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
                                                                                              ^^^^^^
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/kimurai-1.4.0/lib/kimurai/base.rb:128:in `block in crawl!'
```

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'kimurai'

class WebScrapper < Kimurai::Base
  @name = "web_scrapper_spider"
  @engine = :mechanize
  @start_urls = ["https://metaruby.com/"]
  @config = {
      user_agent: "Chrome/68.0.3440.84"
    }

  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
    blogs = []
    response.xpath("//table[@class='topic-list']//tbody//tr").each do |tr|
      scrapped_data = {
                        title: tr.at('td[1]//span').text,
                        category: tr.at('td[1]//div//span').text,
                        date: tr.at('td[3]').text.strip
                      }
      blogs << scrapped_data
      save_to "results.json", scrapped_data.as_json, format: :json
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative gem, fork of Kimurai exists: https://github.com/glaucocustodio/tanakai
It may help for the Ruby 3+ version compatibility, following the answer of KunalK.
(On my side I still have the same problem, but in case you find a way to resolve it)

Answer (score 0):

From the logs posted in the question, it is clear that you are using Ruby version 3.1.2.

The gem [Kimura](https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework) that you are using is not maintained since 2020 and hence it is not compatible with Ruby 3.x due to the [separation of positional and keyword arguments from 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0).

Refer to Kimura [issue #66](https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework/issues/66) for more details and updates on the reported issue.

For now, you can use the gem Kimura with earlier Ruby versions.
I tried your code with Ruby 2.x and found no issues with the code.